# Not getting any waveforms when simulating test bench (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, hdl, modelsim

I'm a beginner in Verilog HDL programming. I'm using ModelSim software.

The problem is when running test bench with the code below I cannot see any waveforms in the wave window:

fulladder.v:

```
module fulladder (carry, sum, A, B, Cin);
output carry, sum;
input A, B, Cin;
wire [2:0] w;

and (w[0], B, Cin);
and (w[1], A, Cin);
and (w[2], A, B);
or (carry, w[0], w[1], w[2]);
xor (sum, A, B, Cin);
endmodule
```

fulladder_testbench.v:

```
module fulladder_testbench;
reg A, B, Cin;
wire carry, sum;

fulladder FA(carry, sum, A, B, Cin);

initial
begin       
    A=1'b0; B=1'b0; Cin=1'b0;   //000   at time 0s
    #5 A=1'b1; B=1'b0; Cin=1'b0;    //100   5s
    #5 A=1'b1; B=1'b1; Cin=1'b0;    //110   10s
    #5 A=1'b1; B=1'b1; Cin=1'b1;    //111   15
    #5 A=1'b0; B=1'b1; Cin=1'b1;    //011   20
    #15 A=1'b0; B=1'b0; Cin=1'b1;   //001   35
    #5 $finish;         //  40
end

initial
begin
    $monitor($time, " Carry = %b, Sum = %b\n", carry, sum);
end

endmodule
```

[image: Wave Window image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I actually solved it. I just needed to drag the inputs/ouputs into the waveform window before running it. Very noobie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it. I just needed to drag the inputs/ouputs into the waveform window before running it. Very noobie mistake

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code as is.

```
initial 
begin 
 $shm_open("waves.shm"); $shm_probe("AS"); 
end
```

Comment: Hello, I added that snippet in the fulladder_testbench.v file just before the 'endmodule' statement and it still isn't working

Comment: This are the errors: ```Warning: (vsim-PLI-3003) [TOFD] - System task or function '$shm_open' is not defined.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /fulladder_testbench File: C:/Users/drb_4/OneDrive/Escritorio/HDL/test/fulladder_testbench.v Line: 8
# ** Warning: (vsim-PLI-3003) [TOFD] - System task or function '$shm_probe' is not defined.
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /fulladder_testbench File: C:/Users/drb_4/OneDrive/Escritorio/HDL/test/fulladder_testbench.v Line: 8
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save the wave to be able to debug after the simulation is done, you need to dump the waveform.
There is a lot of ways to do that depending on your simulator. And dump files may be huge.
Mentor has its own format called WLF (wave log file). But the IEEE standard one is value change dump file (VCD) that can be viewed by many tools. See the $dumpfile and $dumpvars.
For modelsim you can dump the VCD and use vcd2wlf to generate a WLF.
Or use *add wave* in the sim command line, this will create the WLF file directly.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you haven't added any wave. right click on the FA and select add wav

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).